# ASP.NET MVC LINQtoSQL

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an entity with a child. How can I display a count of the children for each object in my view?

I've tried:

```
<% foreach (var item in Model) { %>
    <%: item.JobTitle %>
    <%: item.EmploymentApps.Count %> Applications
<% } %>
```

but I'm getting a runtime error:

```
Compiler Error Message: CS0012: The type 'System.Data.Linq.EntitySet`1<T0>' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Data.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.
```

Comment: Do what the error says. Your view needs to reference the LINQ assembly. You can do this in Web.config or in the .aspx itself. Also, you probably want `Count()` rather than `Count`. And a C# tutorial. :)

Comment: @bzlm: Perhaps E-Madd has never added a reference to a project and needs help there.

Comment: @JYelton Perhaps this is not the correct forum then. :)

Answer (score 3):

I'm imagining you are having this issue because your domain objects are defined in a separate assembly to your web app (this is good), and your web app previously hasn't had a reference to System.Data.Linq.  It's an easy fix, simply add this to your web.config:

```
<add assembly="System.Data.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
```

You get that particular error because the `EmploymentApps` property returns an `EntitySet<EmploymentApp>` instance.  Direct references to types referenced by an intermediatary assembly will generate that exception.